# When looking at a code diff in Gerrit, is it possible to hide comments?

Tags: gerrit

When Gerrit displays comments, they are shown in between the lines of code. This makes it difficult to read and follow the flow of code, especially when the comments have developed into a thread.

Is there an option to temporarily hide these comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to hide the comments, all you can do is to press "Shift-e" to collapse all comment threads.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not an option when the last answer was accept, but you can look at the keyboard shortcuts at

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-review-ui.html#keyboard-shortcuts

You can see in there that you can hide/show comments in diffs by pressing `h`

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution, just run this code in console:

```
document.getElementById('app').shadowRoot
    .getElementById('app-element').shadowRoot
    .querySelector('main')
    .querySelector('gr-diff-view').shadowRoot
    .querySelector('gr-diff-host').shadowRoot
    .querySelectorAll('.comment-thread')
    .forEach(i => i.style.display='none')
```

Because there are lots of #shadow-root element in gerrit page, you cannot get the comment thread element by `document.getElementsByClassName('comment-thread')`.

To make this easier, you can use chrome plugin [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) and add script [Hide gerrit comment](https://greasyfork.org/zh-CN/scripts/469806-hide-gerrit-comment). Then a button "Hide comment" will show up at top right buttons list.
[image]